# Why do I always get a cors error that wildcard * is not allowed, although I specified a origin on the server?

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, graphql

I created a simple graphQL Chat with Apollo Server and Apollo Client.

It also uses session cookies so I initialized the server with the npm package `cors` like this:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  })
);
```

On the client side I use apollo client and create a http link like this:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  credentials: "include"
});
```

So I include credentials and the server has the origin of my client (which is indeed http://localhost:3000 - create-react-app default).

When I want to run a query I get this error in my browser console:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Why does it say that the response header has a wildcard * set, but on cors I set a specific origin, so it should not be a wildcard right?

What am I missing here guys? I also restarted both servers of course.

When I set the client like this:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  credentials: "same-origin"
});
```

I don't get an error message from cors, but I don't receive a cookie from the server. Cookies work because on graphQL Playground everything works as expected.

If you want to see the full code: https://github.com/SelfDevTV/graphql-simple-chat

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is solved.

In my `index.js` file from the server. 
A few lines below I apply the express app as a middleware to the apollo server instance like so:

`server.applyMiddleware({ app });`

But this overrides cors options I set above.

So I have to call it like this: `server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: false });`

Now everything works perfectly :)

Comment: This is just turning off cors.  The better solution would be to set up a proxy for local development in your package.json `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000/",` which tells react to proxy port 4000 through your app for development.  For production, you'll need to bundle your server and front-end together

Comment: Is it really turning it off? Because that would mean that credentials would not be passed to the client? So cookies would not work, but they do this way?
Do I set this proxy you mentioned in the package.json from the create-react-app folder or the server's package.json?

Comment: Yes, `cors: false` is turning cors off, which has nothing to do with credentials or cookies.  It's a security protection that is much better explained here: https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b As far as the proxy, you put that in your react package.json.

Comment: Ok when I set this proxy. What exactly do I have to do next. Enable cors with the cors package like this: `app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"]
  })
);`
And also set `cors:true` on the apollo server instance? 
And on the client I can set `{credentials: "same-origin" }`? 
Is this correct like this?
**EDIT:** Does not work this way. `same-origin` works but no cookie. `include` same cors error with the wildcard.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything explicitly on either side, just set the proxy on the react side and it will hit `http://localhost:4000` as if it was hitting `http://localhost:3000`.  Here are the official docs: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: Another thing I tried.
* Set proxy on the `package.json`
* disable the cors package 
* enable cors like this on the server: `server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  }
});`

This works but not when I set origin: `same-origin` on the client, so it's still not secure for production when I use `include` right?

Comment: The react proxy only works in development.  For production you'll want to serve both the react build and the api endpoints from the same (express?) web server so it won't be a cross origin request.  This doesn't work in a dev environment because typically you'll start react with `npm run start` and the server with something like `npm run server` and they can't share the same port.  The react proxy deals with that issue.  For prod you'll want a static build and serve it up from where you serve up the API

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same issue

Comment: Hi, yes my problem is solved, see my solution up there.

Comment: Some comments here got me a bit worried, that maybe CORS processing was just off with `cors: false` . I tested it and verified that the app's CORS middleware was indeed invoked for all gql calls. Great tip.

Answer (score 9):

You can instead tell the Apollo server how to configure cors.

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true
}

server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  cors: corsOptions
})
```

Then you can eliminate the express cors middleware entirely.

Comment: This worked for me. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: When I used `http://localhost:3000` or `true` as my origin it worked, but not when I added `*`, `/`, or `/*` on the end of the url, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/`. I also added this as a variable in my `env.dev` file: `CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000`, and then loaded it in the server index via `origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL`, which worked well