# How to correctly state cors origin in Backend? Nodejs Express app CORS Origin Error: PreflightWildcardOriginNotAllowed

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, cors

Background info: frontend gets backend info via GraphQL API. Frontend uses Apollo Client. Backend is Node.js using express, cors, express-session, and Apollo Server.
Frontend at `localhost:3000`, Backend at `localhost:4000`. I am sending a cookie with the request

Current error I have: `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightWildcardOriginNotAllowed`. I'm confused because I believe I explicitly stated the origin in the backend.

Relevant frontend code:

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  credentials: "include" // TODO change to same-origin before deploy
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})
```

Relevant backend code:

```
const app = express()
  
  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }))

  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session)
  const redisClient = redis.createClient()

  app.use(
    session({
      name: COOKIE_NAME,
      store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
        disableTouch: true,
      }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 81600 * 365,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
        secure: false, // TODO change to true when prod
      },
      secret: "HARDCODED-SECRET", // TODO
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    })
  )
```

I am having big trouble debugging this. How can I know what CORS was expecting? How to debug CORS related things? I already made sure the problem is not related to a wrong import problem.

I suspect the following line of code

`app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }))`

is **not** doing anything. But that is just a suspicion, I don't really know what I'm talking about.

In Network, 2 requests are sent. One with the actual graphql query. It fails and does not get a response due to that error. I'll paste data from Chrome F12 Network tab:

```
-General-
Request URL: http://localhost:4000/graphql
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

-Request Headers-
Provisional headers are shown
accept: */*
content-type: application/json
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36

-Request Payload-
{operationName: "Login", variables: {username: "a", password: "a"},…}
operationName: "Login"
query: "mutation Login($username: String!, $password: String!) {↵  login(options: {username: $username, password: $password}) {↵    username↵    id↵    createdAt↵    __typename↵  }↵}↵"
variables: {username: "a", password: "a"}
```

The second request is a 204 OK no data. I don't know why this one is sent at all, but it might contain relevant information. Pasting:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4000/graphql
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:4000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 13 Apr 2021 14:17:02 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6,ja;q=0.5
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:4000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
```

I haven't kept track of all things I've tried, sorry. If I manage to find the fix, I'll post it right away. I've never got a cors related bug before. This also means I'm pretty much clueless about this issue.

EDIT: To pinpoint the issue further, I put a /test endpoint in the backend, and I'm unable to access it using axios in the frontend. The error is CORS error: Cors Disabled Scheme.

Comment: Try `app.use(cors())` without passing any options.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: do you have an apollo middleware? like this: `apolloServer.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: false,
  });`

Comment: Yes. I had it without that `cors: false` part. I've now tried it with `cors: false` and the error is the same. I got extra info, I put a /test endpoint in the backend, and I'm unable to access it using axios in the frontend due to CORS stuff. More info on main post, it's edited.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954070/why-do-i-always-get-a-cors-error-that-wildcard-is-not-allowed-although-i-spec -> Did you try these answers?

Comment: Cors errors can be a living nightmare. So, its mostly trial and error.

Comment: This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/60679615/15623042 just fixed it. Thanks! Pretty good. I was losing my mind. I just realized, probably applyMiddleware of apollo-server was overwriting my CORS config? Setting it as cors: corsConfig made it stop doing that.