# CORS The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' can't not be wild card "*" in Apollo server using node.js

Tags: node.js, cors, apollo-server

So I want to test my cookie in apollo server, according to the website, it said I have to set origin to https://studio.apollographql.com  and set the credential to true, so I applied middle ware cors in my expresss like below

```js
const app = express();
app.use(cors({
        credentials:true,
        origin: 'https://studio.apollographql.com'
    }));
```

so it returned The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' can't not be wild card "*" ... in console, so I changed my origin to see if this middleware did work , I changed to
https://google.com and it went like this below , so I think my middleware is working ,
but why does it return wild card , when my setting is right ?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

So I believe this was the same problem in this article

[Why do I always get a cors error that wildcard * is not allowed, although I specified a origin on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56954070/why-do-i-always-get-a-cors-error-that-wildcard-is-not-allowed-although-i-spec)

And I solved it